Why do electrical showers in Thailand use ELCBs instead of RCDs?
I recently visited Thailand, and noticed that all the electrical shower units used Earth-leakage circuit breakers for protection.
They all had "ELCB Test" buttons.
When reading on ELCBs on Wikipedia, they are described as

An earth-leakage circuit breaker (ELCB) is a safety device used in electrical installations with high Earth impedance to prevent shock.

Why do these shower units not use RCDs (Residual Current Device) for protection? Is the "high impedance" part relevant here?

What type of grounding system do they use?

Can you post a pic of the ELCB with readable fine print? There are several types, it may actually be a RCD

I think it is a case of mistranslation / local naming convention, and that @bobflux is correct: these are RCDs that are sold locally as "ELCB". They are two pole things: L & N only. The earth wire does not go through the breaker as it would if it was an ELCB. The earth wire often don't exist to begin with, so an ELCB would be useless anyway.

An example of a breaker commonly found in shower heaters in TH is Kyokuto KD-L223SC. If you google it, you will see that most local shops sell it as an ELCB, the label on the device says RCCB, but it also has overcurrent protection so it is actually an RCD.

@KristoferA The terminology is confusing. RCD and RCCB mean the same thing. If combined with overcurrent protection, then it's an RCBO.

@justme thanks for the correction.

i found this question on the hot network questions and came here solely out of curiosity about how "electrical shower units" could exist as it sounds like a method for electrocuting unsuspecting victims.  Thanks @KristoferA for the comment clarifying it is for a shower heater!

@michael Yes, in this climate, centrally heated water is not a common thing. Instead, you will find direct water heaters in the 3-9kW range, or (rarely) stored water heaters in the 1-5kW range just for use in showers and bath tubs. And yes: accidental electrocutions are common for a variety of reasons.

They use different terms for the same device in differect countries. Sometimes there is also a misuse in terms in everyday language.
From the same Wikipedia page you quoted, also in the case of ELCB term, they used to be voltage-sensing, but when current sensing devices came to market, the term ELCB stuck because it was already established. So that's why even today the same name for two differently operating devices cause confusion.
So basically, RCD, ELCB and RCCB, RCBO and GFCI could virtually mean the same thing to most people.
Technically, an RCD, RCCB,  ELCB is not a circuit breaker with overcurrent protection.
When the units combine earth leakage detection and disconnection with a more common circuit breaker, i.e. combine RCD of some type with a regular overcurrnet MCB, the resulting device is called RCBO or GFCI.
But it's not really important what the devices are called or what the official term in that country is. What's important is that a correct device with correct functions and features are used correctly where they need to.
